# Shopify Liquid - Get the URL for a variant's image

Tags: shopify, liquid

On a Shopify product page, I can loop through all the variants and get information about them like this:

```
  {% for variants in product.variants %}
  {{ variants.id }}<br>
  {{ variants.sku }}<br>
  {{ variants.title}}<br>
  {{ variants.price | divided_by: 100}}<br>
  {% endfor %}
```

This works perfectly fine, however when I try and get the variant image in the loop like this:

```
{{ variants.image}}
```

I have also tried using:

```
{{ variants.featured_image.src}}
```

Which produces exactly the same result.

The output is simpy `products` and then the name of the image file. For example '`products/my-image.jpg`'.

This is obviously not the path to the image and when I try and display this within an `image` tag, a broken image is produced.

I am trying to get the path to the image that is stored on Shopify's CDN for this variant product, which will look something like `https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0022/4572/2212/products/WI1M1L1F1B1_grande.jpg?v=1656698226`.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved within the loop I am using above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this

```
{{ variant.image.src | product_img_url: '200x' }}
```

I suggest you to take a look here to find many other useful functions: https://www.shopify.ca/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet

Also is useful to download a free theme (Dawn for example) and use it as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example to show each variant image and url :

```
<div class="product_thumbnails">
{% for variant in product.variants %}
            <a href="{{ variant.url }}">
              <div class="h-[50px] w-[50px] bg-[#E6ECEB] rounded shrink-0 p-1">
          
                {{ variant.image | image_url: width: 50 | image_tag }}
  
  
                  </div>
            </a>
            
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```